# How to let players move to another field properly?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm making a monopoly-like game, and I'm almost done. The only problem I've got is the chancecard. When a player gets a chancecard he might be asked to move to a specific field. So my problem is that the game doesn't move the car (player) to this specific field why? It moves the player to a random field.

```
import desktop_resources.GUI;


public class Movecard extends Card {

protected int move;

public Movecard(String text, int move) {
    this.text=text;
    this.move=move;
}

public void activateCard(Player s) {
    GUI.showMessage(text);
    GUI.removeCar(s.getField(), s.getName());
    int Move= s.getField()+move;
    s.setField(Move);
    GUI.setCar(s.getField(), s.getName());
    Matador.fields[s.getField()].landonField(s);
}
```

}

```
public abstract class Kort {
protected String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public abstract void activateCard(Player s);
```

}

Comment: Hard to know without understanding what a field is and how it's used elsewhere (numeric position around the board? Does it wrap if you set a number higher than the number of fields? Is the card asking the player to move x positions ahead of where they are or should it move exactly to the `move` position?).

Comment: A field is a: street (you can buy it, and if someone lands on it they've to pay you), refuge (if you land on it you get moeny), ships (same as street), labor camps (same as street)

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a move to a specific field but a move to a field `move` fields away from the player's current field.

> int Move= s.getField()+move;

If you want to set the player to a specific field, you have set the player to predefined field-reference.

```
int Move= move;
```

or directly

```
s.setField(move);
```

Comment: The chancecard is a card that tells you to pay/recieve money or to move to  a field from the cardlist. It is random which one of the fields in the cardlist

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: Have tried it but it still moves the player to a field which isn't in the cardlist

Comment: @Hodhod where do you pick a field from the cardlist and how?

Comment: hmmm I tell it `s.getField` which is from the game itself. Do you want to see the cardlist or...?

Comment: And it gets the field information from `landonField`

Comment: @Hodhod You should try to debug/print the expected and actual values directly before call of .landOnField() and after it to find out where the wrong field value comes from.

Comment: I've tried it, and it always sets the car the field +2 so if it has to set the car on field 11 it sets it on 13

Comment: For the class "Movecard"? It's still the same except for one thing; I've changed  `s.setField(Move)` to `s.setField(Move-1)` as the fields starts by 0 and not 1, but I still have the same problem. Now it moves +1 instead of +2

Comment: @Hodhod how do you calculate Move? If you still calculate Move as `int Move= s.getField()+move` its a movement relative to the current position of the player instead of a movement to the absolut position to the the field with the index `move` when setting Move as `int Move= move`

Answer (score 0):

You are not moving the player to the field with the index `move`, but advance the player by `move` fields.

Try `s.setField(move);` instead.

Comment: Have tried it but it still moves the player to a field which isn't in the cardlist